# Heterodyne detector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, observables

In which sense an heterodyne detector does not measure an observable? I mean, its POVM is proportional to the projector on coherent states, and the coherent states are an overcomplete set for the radiation Hilbert space, why this is not an observable?